# Replacing a Marvin window sill

Tags: replacement, sill

I need advice on replacing a rotten Marvin window sill. It is a three-piece sash window with heavy mullions. Diagram of mullion to sill would also be useful. Thanks

Comment: This is going to need a few pictures.  There are just too many designs out there to even approach this without any.

Comment: While not Marvin, I had a similar problem with another manufacturer's windows.  I contacted them and they sent me a nice supply of the milled sill pieces free.  It may be worth a try.

Comment: Even if you had to pay for the manufacturer's milled sill pieces it would still be a whole lot better than trying to make the pieces from scratch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll more info (e.g. pictures) before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.